# UIImagePickerController really slow when calling alloc init

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a view controller that is presented on pressing on one of the tabs in a tabBarController. In this view controller I initialise a UIImagePickerController in the viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Set imagePicker
    //-------------------------//
    _imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    _imagePicker.delegate = self;
    _imagePicker.videoMaximumDuration = 10.0f;
}
```

The intention is to then display the UIImagePickerController at a later time when a button is pressed. For some reason though when the tab icon is pressed for this view controller, there is a 3-4 second hang while this viewDidLoad method is running. When I comment out the line     _imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] there is no hang time and the view controller loads immediately - as it should.

Does anyone know why allocating and initialising the UIImagePickerController is taking so long? If so, is there a way to speed it up other than running it as a background process? It seems like this is not normal behaviour.

I am using iOS7, and I am not calling viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear.

Comment: Have you try different devices ?

Comment: yes have tried different devices - same problem on all

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Turns out this is only a problem when in debug mode (when the iPhone is connected and running through Xcode). Once the same app is running without being connected to Xcode the lag doesn't occur.

Comment: When the popover loading UIImagePickerController is popped out, it is too slow regardless of XCode's debug mode.

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer.  The lag time with UIImagePickerController consistently grows when you revisit the subsequent view and call it.  Eventually the app will crash.  Especially if you have multiple views calling the UIImagePickerController.

Answer (score 0):

Try this iOS 12

```
//show a HUD or activityIndicator
dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("openPhotosCamera", NULL), ^{
   
    UIImagePickerController *mediaUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //hide HUD or activityIndicator
        [presenter presentViewController:mediaUI animated:YES completion:nil];
    });
});
```

**presenter is yourViewController / self

Comment: iOS 13 : [UIImagePickerController alloc] cannot be called on a background thread.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad{

    //Set imagePicker
    //-------------------------//
    _imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    _imagePicker.delegate = self;
    _imagePicker.videoMaximumDuration = 10.0f;

[super viewDidLoad];
```

Comment: this makes no difference to the lag time

Comment: Try this 

`UIImagePickerController *imagepicker;



- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    //show camera...
    if(!imagepicker){
        imagepicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
        imagepicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

   }

}`