# Open Camera Instantly when view appears

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera

I have a requirement in my app in which I need to open a camera instantly.
But when I come to that ViewController opening camera is taking time for few seconds. Can any one help me. 
I have tried with queues blocks but this doesn't work. 
This is the code i have tried so far :==

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {

            [super viewDidLoad];
            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^ {
                [self onClickCamera:nil];

                //Your code goes in here
                NSLog(@"Main Thread Code");

            }];
//    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
//        [self onClickCamera:nil];
//    });

//    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.MyQueue", NULL);
//    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
//        [self onClickCamera:nil];
//
//        // Do some computation here.
//        
//        // Update UI after computation.
//        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
//            // Update the UI on the main thread.
//        });
//    });


    }

        - (IBAction)onClickCamera:(id)sender
        {
            NSLog(@"CALeed");
            UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            picker.delegate = self;
            picker.allowsEditing = NO;
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
        }
```

Comment: SHOW UR TRIED CODE

Comment: how you implemented camera? Please update the question with code

Comment: why even [NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock: ?? ViewDidLoad always gets called on main thread only which is associated with serialized main queue itself. The un-necessary context switching makes no much sense

Comment: @SandeepBhandari I am just trying things to make it work.

Comment: @niharika : Writing code without knowing how it would work will not help u get it to work :) Thats what I was trying to point out :) Hope my answer helps

Comment: put your code either in viewDidAppear or viewDidLoad. it will work after that.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues :

**Issue 1:**

In viewDidLoad view has not yet finished rendering its layout yet. So trying to present something over a view which is still rendering, will obviously add the delay. Presenting camera will be triggered only after view finishes laying out its layout.

So move the code from `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidAppear`

```
 - (void) viewDidAppear {
     [super viewDidAppear];
     [self onClickCamera:nil];
 }
```

**Issue 2:**

More of a warning then error.

why even `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:` ?? ViewDidLoad always gets called on main thread only which is associated with serialized main queue itself. The un-necessary context switching makes no much sense

Comment: @niharika : Whats the issue now ??

Comment: @niharika : is it a permission issue ? You see a black screen ? Have u given permission to ur app to use camera ? Added camera usage description to your app's info.plist ?

Comment: It is taking time like 3 4 seconds before presenting camera. no this is not a permission issue.

Comment: @niharika : Is it happening when u are debugging only ? Because its a known issue with UIImagePicker controller when in debug session it takes more time to open have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353492/uiimagepickercontroller-really-slow-when-calling-alloc-init

Comment: @niharika : So please try running it rather than debugging it and check the performance second use different device to test it

Comment: Ok i will check with these cases. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @SandeepBhandari's answer. You can make change to the following line apart from calling the method to present camera in viewDidAppear() to reduce the delay:

Change

```
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

to

```
[self presentViewController:picker animated:NO completion:NULL];
```

Adding more to this you can predefine your pickerController globally and set all it's properties and parameters in viewDidLoad()

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = NO;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

}
```

Also initially you can set the **backgroundColour** of your viewController's main view to black or similar to the colour of your launchScreen to avoid seeing that glitches when camera is presented.

You can also use **CATransition** to reduce time like follows

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    [transition setDuration:0];
    [transition setType:kCATransitionFromBottom];
    [transition setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
    [picker.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransitionFromBottom];
```

and then present the picker controller.

Well this is yet not guaranteed to give you desire results as presenting something will obviously take some fraction of time. If you have a good usage of camera in your app then i would **suggest** to use custom class for it and use **AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer** to show the camera.

Comment: This worked but initially it shows a blink of white screen!

Comment: Yea that what i said that presenting something will definitely take some fraction of time.

Comment: I have updated my answer review it. Lets hope it helps you :)